# Google Analytics API sometimes returns nothing

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the Google Analytics API in JavaScript within an MVC project.  When I make my queries, I sometimes get data and sometimes get an empty object.  There are no errors in the console when this happens.  Also, it only happens with certain queries and never happens with others.
  I don't think it's a sampling issue, because I am usually dealing with low numbers (usually single digit).  Also, I have tried setting the sampling level to high with no change in the behavior.
  Here is an example of a query that sometimes returns empty for me:

```
var rangedFirstLoad = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                'ids': viewId,
                'start-date': minDateChart,
                'end-date': maxDateChart,
                'metrics': 'ga:totalEvents',
                'dimensions': 'ga:operatingSystem',
                'filters': filterQuery + ';ga:eventAction==First Load',
                'samplingLevel': 'higher_precision'
            },
            chart: {
                'container': 'chart-rangedFirstLoad-container',
                'type': 'TABLE',
                'options': {
                    'width': '100%'
                }
            }
        });
        rangedFirstLoad.on('success', function (resp) {
         //do stuff
        });
```

The variables are the same for every query that I use.  'First Load' is an event I created in my app.  I've tried with and without the higher precision.  Out of the twenty queries that I use, only two of them sometimes return empty.
  Thank you.